# Объединить clipPath, pattern и linearGradient в SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Я пытаюсь создать фон, состоящий из градиента нескольких точек, от зеленого до желтого, слева направо. Поэтому идея заключалась в том, чтобы создать путь, заполнить его градиентом и `clipPath` с `pattern`:

```html
<svg width='100' height='100' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width=".1" height=".1">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" fill="green"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <clipPath id="img-dotted-clip">
      <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" clip-path="url(#img-dotted-clip)"></path>
</svg>
```

Градиент работает нормально, `clip-path` работает нормально (автономно). Однако они не собираются вместе.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Combine clipPath, pattern, and linearGradient in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49427368/7394871) от участника  [@sdvnksv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2210364/sdvnksv).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49427368/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Только форма элементов в `<clipPath>` имеет значение. Цвет и заливка игнорируются, поэтому вы не можете этого сделать.

Но вместо этого вы можете использовать `<mask>`:

```html
<svg width='100' height='100' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width=".1" height=".1">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" fill="white"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)"></path>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428854/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Примеры анимации

Техника комбинации `clipPath`, `pattern` и `linearGradient` даёт широкий диапазон для творчества в веб строительстве.

- Изменяя параметры `width`, `height` в `pattern` можно получить разные
  формы шаблона для заполнения фигур, а также горизонтальные и
  вертикальные полосы.
- Применение различных команд анимации позволяет оживить картинку.
- Добавляя текст можно получить дополнительные эффекты.
- Добавление маски вместе с градиентом даёт возможность получить
  разноцветный круг с мягкими градиентными цветами.

**Вертикальные полосы**

Получаются за счет превышения в несколько раз ширины над высотой в патерне `width="0.05" height="0.01"`.

Анимация полос достигается изменением радиуса окружности, входящей в паттерн:

```
 <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4;4" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </circle>`
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="greenyellow"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width="0.05" height="0.01">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
     <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4;4" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)">
   <animate attributeName="cx1" values="50;175;50" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
      </circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)"></path>
</svg>
```

**Горизонтальные полосы**

Здесь у патерна - `width="0.005" height="0.05">` ширина меньше высоты

```html
<svg width='200' height='200' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="greenyellow"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width="0.005" height="0.05">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
     <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)">
  
      </circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)"></path>
</svg>
```

**Горизонтальные полосы в градиентном цветном круге**

Добавляем к маске строку с шириной строки

```
<mask id="img-dotted-mask">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="3"  fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"> </circle>    </mask>`
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="greenyellow"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width="0.005" height="0.05">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
     <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="3"  fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"> </circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text font-size="18" x="20" y="50" fill="dodgerblue"> click me</text>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)"></path>
 </svg>
```

**Изменение размера фигур паттерна**

Достигается изменением радиуса окружностей, входящих в паттерн

```
<circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4;4" dur="8s" 
 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</circle>
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200' viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="img-dotted-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="greenyellow"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <pattern id="img-dotted-dots" x="0" y="0" width="0.05" height="0.05">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="4" fill="white">
     <animate attributeName="r" values="4;2;1;2;4;4" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="img-dotted-mask">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#img-dotted-dots)"></circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" fill="url(#img-dotted-gradient)" mask="url(#img-dotted-mask)"></path>
</svg>
```