# Почему pattern не заполняет фон?

Tags: html5, вёрстка, svg

Почему в коде ниже `pattern` не заполняет фон?

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 150 150' preserveAspectRatio='none' >
 <defs>

   <pattern id='pattern' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x='0' y='0' width='150' height='150'>
      <q fill='#85D2FF' fill-opacity='0.7'>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
      </q>
   </pattern>

 </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: url(#pattern); stroke: #000000;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: там тег `q`, может по-этому?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT причем тег html5 если тут нет тегов html5  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Две неточности, одну было очень трудно найти групповой тег у вас был `q` надо `g`

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150"  viewBox="0 0 150 150"
 preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid crimson"  >
 <defs>

   <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150">
      <g fill="#85D2FF" fill-opacity="0.7">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
      </g>
   </pattern>

 </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#pattern); stroke: #000000;"/>
</svg>
```

2. Нужно изменить размеры плитки патерна

   было  `width="150" height="150"` нужно `width="20" height="20"`

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150"  viewBox="0 0 150 150"
 preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid crimson"  >
 <defs>

   <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
      <g fill="#85D2FF" fill-opacity="0.7">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
      </g>
   </pattern>

 </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#pattern); stroke: #000000;"/>
</svg>
```

Поясняющий рисунок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее о pattern [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) и [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875)

Красивые [примеры анимации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808262/28748) патернов